# React native firebase getToken() not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-firebase

Just upgraded to react native 0.61.5 and react native firebase (v5.5.7) `getToken()` function doesn't seem to run or it just seems to hang on the `await`.

I have this function:

```
async function updatePushNotificationsEnabled(isEnabled: boolean) {
  return updateUser({ pushNotificationsEnabled: isEnabled, firebaseId: await getToken() })
}
```

which in turn is calling:

```
async function getToken() {
  try {
    return FCM().getToken();
  } catch (error) {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

If I follow https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/messaging/device-token I can't seem to get a token back from the server. If I try `console.log(await getToken())` I don't get anything in console. If I `console.log(FCM().getToken())` I get a promise in the console. What am I doing wrong? or am I needing to upgrade to the latest version of react native firebase?

I have also checked permissions and the permission on the device is on so returns true.

I do have a function to check for permissions but this is done earlier in the app and not at the point of what I am doing.

```
async function requestPermissionIfNeeded() {
  try {
    if (await FCM().hasPermission()) {
      return true;
    }
    await FCM().requestPermission();
    return await FCM().hasPermission();
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: what version of rnfirebase are you using?

Comment: i am using version 5.5.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What ended up working for us on iOS was updating the react native firebase library to `v5.6.0` (as we aren't in a position to update to v6 yet).

This required us to update the underlying Podfile Firebase versions to `~6.13.0` as per the guide. Did a `pod install` and it looks like the `getToken` function is working again.

Comment: Podfile Firebase version  ~6.13.0 contain UIWebView  you will get this message from Apple -
"MS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will no longer accept submissions of new apps that use UIWebView as of April 30, 2020 and app updates that use UIWebView as of December 2020. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability".

Answer (score 0):

please update request() && getToken() function like

```
async requestPermission() {
        try {
          await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
          this.getToken();
        } catch (error) {
          alert('permission rejected');
        }
    }

async getToken() {
    let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('device_token');
    if (!fcmToken) {
        fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
        if (fcmToken) {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('device_token', fcmToken);
        }
    } else {
        // do some work
        console.log('Device_token')
        console.log(fcmToken)
    }
}
```

Comment: My issue still stands that I don’t get anything back from getToken. It just doesn’t do anything.

Comment: @saunders i am also facing this issue in 2023. Are you able to resolve it?